# Facebook: how to get users info in news feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get news feeds using

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/home
```

in addition to get the id of the user who post a status or photo,e.g.

`from =             {
                id = 100004146969087;
                name = "Tim";
            };`, I want to get the fullName and profile_img_url of that person. I have to send a request like `/me?fields=picture, username, name` to get the info. How can I get the fullName and profile_img_url of users in my news feed by one request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=from.fields(name,username,picture.type(large))
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use multiply query. JSON-format query, you can find document in facebook developer document.